# Webpack, Typescript, запуск кода после загрузки DOM

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Вопрос заключается в следующем:
Есть класс ts, например меню, элементы которого являются приватным свойством,
в конструкторе они берутся через QuerySelector и им навешивается событие click. но происходит это до загрузки DOM. Есть ли какая-нибудь директива в webpack, tsconfig.json, позволяющая при бандле кода поместить его в document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded, () => {...}); ?
просто добавить этот код не получится, т.к точка входа содержит import-ы с классами как описано выше, в которых требуется загруженный DOM (насколько знаю перед import нельзя вставлять кастомный код js, вот и смотрю в настройки webpack, ts. ничего похожего на нашел, есть идеи?

Comment: небось файл сборки в head размещен?

Comment: Подключено в конце body, через функцию asset (Laravel)

Comment: показывайте код

Comment: Разобрался. при получении элемента в querySelector с классом, забыл точку, все работает